# Is there a comprehensive list of clojure.core macros that take bindings in a vector?

Tags: clojure

I'm looking to get a list of clojure.core symbols that take destructuring forms:

```
(<symbol> [bindings] ~@body)
```

Off the top of my head, I can list `for` `let` `fn` `if-let` `doseq` `defn` `defmacro`.... I'm looking for a more comprehensive list if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this cheat sheet: http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet-clj-1.3/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html, it has a list of special forms that takes destructuring forms, just search for 'binding forms'. Any macro that expands to any of these special forms can destruct its parameters.

Maybe Codeq (http://blog.datomic.com/2012/10/codeq.html) can be used to discover all the macros that expands into one of the special binding forms?

Comment: Thanks! That cheat sheet is really helpful